# Using Css with Asp.net Menu (HoverStyle not taking effect)

Tags: asp.net, css

I have the following code which Im using to create an asp.net menu. I've assigned CssClasses to each of the Dynamic items and created specific classes. However, the dynamicHoverStyle class doesnt take effect. Does anyone know why this is the case ?

```
<asp:Menu ID="Menu1" StaticEnableDefaultPopOutImage="false" runat="server" BackColor="#B5C7DE" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="0.8em" ForeColor="#284E98" Orientation="
    <DynamicHoverStyle CssClass="style1_hover"/>
    <DynamicMenuStyle CssClass="style2" />
    <DynamicMenuItemStyle CssClass="style1" />
    <DynamicSelectedStyle BackColor="#507CD1" />
    <Items>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="Menu A" Value="Menu A">
        <asp:MenuItem Text="Submenu A" Value="Submenu A"></asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="Submenu B" Value="Submenu B"></asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="Submenu C" Value="Submenu C"></asp:MenuItem>
    </Items>

    <StaticHoverStyle />

    <StaticMenuItemStyle BorderColor="Green" BorderWidth="1px" VerticalPadding="8px" />
    <StaticSelectedStyle BackColor="#507CD1" />



.style1 {
    background-color:white;
    border-color:black;
    border:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    padding-left:20px;
    padding-right:20px;
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
}

.style2 {
    background-color:blue;
    border-color:black;
    border:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    padding-left:20px;
    padding-right:20px;
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
}


.style1_hover {
    background-color:blue;
    border-color:black;
    border:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    padding-left:20px;
    padding-right:20px;
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    font-size:large;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a snippet of the html that gets output?

Answer (score 0):

I spent hours on this one myself. :(  The asp:Menu is sorely lacking.

I was using LevelMenuItemStyles like such:

```
<LevelMenuItemStyles>
    <asp:MenuItemStyle CssClass="menuLevel1"/>
    <asp:MenuItemStyle CssClass="menuLevel2"/>
    <asp:MenuItemStyle CssClass="menuLevel3"/>
</LevelMenuItemStyles>
```

to give each level of the menu a different style, but ran into the same problem that the hover styles just were not working.  The solution was to use CSS hover instead.

so instead of...

```
.style1_hover { ... }
```

use

```
.style1:hover { ... }
```

and remove the line.

```
<DynamicHoverStyle CssClass="style1_hover"/>
```

I'm assuming that this works the same when not using level styles.

I realize this question was a while ago, and you have likely moved on or found a solution, but hopefully this helps you or someone else.